# $scope.variable is undefined - AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a query rather than a problem.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-view view-title="Register" ng-controller="RegisterController">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="padding">
    <label class="item item-input ">
      <input type="number" ng-model="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" >
    </label>
    </div>
    <ul class="list card">
      <li>
        {{results}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="padding">
      <button ng-click="addNumber(phone)" class="button button-outline button-block icon-left ion-plus-round button-balanced">Add Number</button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Controller (1st way):**

```
  .controller('RegisterController',function($scope){
    $scope.results=[{number:80970}];
    $scope.addNumber = function(){
    $scope.results.push({number : $scope.phone});
    };
  })
```

**Controller (2nd way):**

```
  .controller('RegisterController',function($scope){
    $scope.results=[{number:80970}];
    $scope.addNumber = function(phone){
    $scope.results.push({number : phone});
    };
  })
```

Here is my problem, `$scope.phone` in the second controller seems to add the phone number in array results. But the first way doesn't add it to results when tested on phone and Chrome.

However, both the ways work fine in JSFiddle when tested.

I am not sure why I need to pass the variable in HTML when I should directly be able to access the controller using `$scope.phone`.

It seems to be like the HTML code is creating another scope. But then, that should be true for JSFiddle too.

I have seen ngRepeat and ngIf creating problems like this one.

How can I fix that?

*p.s.:* I have not passed the variable "phone" in HTML's `addNumber` function for 1st way controller.

Comment: can you put your ,ionContent and ionView directive code or show it in plunker ?

Comment: I have used ionic CSS framework. I will  write in plunker and show an example

Comment: @Fisherman //jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/

Comment: @ChetanShah I think the answer I have marked as duplicate will explain you how it creates a child scope while rendering `ion-content` element.

Comment: @ChetanShah if you found an answer, please post it here and mark as resolver, it would be helpful for someone in the future

Comment: @infaustus: I have already posted the solution above  . and upvoted the resolver. Please tell me in case i need to add anything else. Thanks